# Definition of cross variation of two processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have a question about the following argument. I see in my book a claim that given 2 stochastic integrals :

\begin{align}X_1&:=\int_{0}^{t}f_s\mathsf dM_s\\  X_2&:=\int_{0}^{t}g_s\mathsf dN_s
\end{align}

$N,M$ are some continuous local martingales then

$$\langle X_1,X_2\rangle_t=\int_{0}^{t}f_s g_s \mathsf d\langle M,N\rangle _s$$

What does the notation $ \mathsf d\langle M,N\rangle_s$ means in the sense of quadratic variation and how they got it here?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the result for $X_1 = X_2$, i.e. that $$\langle X_1 \rangle_t = \int_0^t f_s^2 \, d\langle M \rangle_s$$...?

Comment: also in your example :I don't understand the notation  $d<M>_s$ .if M is brownian motion I understand it but for general local martingale I have a problem

Comment: By definition, $(\langle M \rangle_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is an increasing process and therefore in particular of bounded variation. The integral $$\int_0^t f(s)^2 \, d\langle M \rangle_s$$ is a Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral.

Answer (score 1):

$\langle M,N \rangle$ is the cross variation of two processes. It's typically defined with the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) used to calculate a vector inner product from a vector norm:

From Karatzas + Shreve 2nd Edition, 1.5.5, page 31:

> For any two martingales $X, Y \in \mathscr{M}_2$, we define their *cross-variation* process $\langle X, Y \rangle$ by:
>
> \begin{align*}
>   \langle X, Y \rangle_t &\triangleq \frac{1}{4} \left[ \langle X + Y \rangle_t - \langle X - Y \rangle_t \right]; \quad 0 \le t < \infty \\
> \end{align*}

Then the $d\langle M,N \rangle$ notation is the cross variation function being used as an integrator in a Lebesgue-Stieltjes or Riemann-Stieltjes integral.